# Sum a series of rows based on column values in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm successfully adding rows via a Python script to an external .txt file, creating this format:

```
Mike 200 -7 20.0
Dave 200 8 20.0
Andy 200 0 20.0
Mary 100 0 20.0
Mary 100 1 20.0
Jane 200 -7 20.0
Mike 200 -7 20.0
Fred 200 2 20.0
Malcolm 100 -26 20.0
Mike 20 -10 10.0
Mike 200 -10 20.0
Mike 200 -7 20.0
Mike 200 2 20.0
Fred 100 19 20.0
Mike 200 -19 20.0
Jane 200 -7 20.0
Jane 100 -26 20.0
Malcolm 200 -15 20.0
```

I now need to construct a loop in my main python file that will sum the final column based on the first name (first column) e.g. Mike should equal 130, Dave should equal 20, Mary should equal 40, Jane should equal 60 etc

In trying to break down the problem, I thought I'd manually test one name to start with (using `v`) and have got this far

```
vol_amount = ""
with open("MyTest.txt", "r") as vol:
    for v in vol:
        v = "Mike"
        for s in v[0]:
            vol_amount += int(s[3])

print(vol_amount)
```

I can't seem to get past this point.

Can anyone give any pointers as to what my for loop should be to loop through each of the names in turn, summing up their values from the fourth column? Ideally without using pandas or any add-ons.

I'm sure a for loop can do this.

Thanks

Comment: s in v[0] in this case will always be M

Comment: don’t set v to anything, v should be one row.. you can split it on white space so then you can do [0] to get the first col etc

Comment: Yes you're quite right - this was part of my testing. I've changed this back to vol_amount

Comment: mad.meesh can you show me what you mean. I've now removed `v = "mike"` and it comes back with `vol_amount += int(s[3]) IndexError: string index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean way to approach this problem is to read each line from the file and split the line by white space and store it into an array. You can then index the array for the specific values you're interested in.

I would suggest using a `dictionary` to store the sums of a particular name as you iterate through your whole file.

This is an example working code for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
store = {}
with open('data.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        values = line[:-1].split(" ")
        if values[0] not in store:
            store[values[0]] = float(values[3])
        else:
            store[values[0]] += float(values[3])
```

Now if you were interested in a specific name's value you can search for that name in the dictionary:

```
print(store['Mike']) # output is 130.0
print(store['Mary']) # output is 40.0
print(store['Dave']) # output is 20.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helpful!

Comment: No problem! Using a library like pandas will make your life easier but I understand that's a project limitation you might be have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using `pandas`, you can get rid of a lot of manual labor.

Setup (you can skip this and pass the name of your actual file to `read_csv` in the next step)

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> content = '''Mike 200 -7 20.0
... Dave 200 8 20.0
... Andy 200 0 20.0
... Mary 100 0 20.0
... Mary 100 1 20.0
... Jane 200 -7 20.0
... Mike 200 -7 20.0
... Fred 200 2 20.0
... Malcolm 100 -26 20.0
... Mike 20 -10 10.0
... Mike 200 -10 20.0
... Mike 200 -7 20.0
... Mike 200 2 20.0
... Fred 100 19 20.0
... Mike 200 -19 20.0
... Jane 200 -7 20.0
... Jane 100 -26 20.0
... Malcolm 200 -15 20.0'''
>>> 
>>> fake_file = StringIO(content)
```

Solution

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(fake_file, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
>>> df.groupby(0)[3].sum()
0
Andy        20.0
Dave        20.0
Fred        40.0
Jane        60.0
Malcolm     40.0
Mary        40.0
Mike       130.0
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Here, you would use

```
df = pd.read_csv(YOUR_FILENAME_HERE, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

when not starting from a string.

**edit**: standard library solution:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> rows = sorted(line.split() for line in fake_file)
>>> grouper = groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(0))
>>> {name: sum(float(list(lst)[-1]) for lst in lists) for name, lists in grouper}
{'Malcolm': 40.0, 'Andy': 20.0, 'Fred': 40.0, 'Mary': 40.0, 'Mike': 130.0, 'Jane': 60.0, 'Dave': 20.0}
```

Comment: Thank you - but ideally not using pandas. Is there a way without using such a library?

Comment: @user9099702 added a solution without pandas.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ideally it'd be a totally clean way of achieving this, no imports or other libraries.

Comment: @user9099702 thinking of using the standard library as 'unclean' strikes me as odd, but at least you now have three alternative solutions. 